# Can a dishwasher be installed 8 feet from sink

Tags: dishwasher, pump

I bought a new dishwasher, and the installer said they would not recommend installing it away from the sink (next to a lazy Susan 8 feet from sink pipes) because the pump is not strong enough to pump water away.

Do you agree that 8 feet is too far away from the drains to install a dishwasher?

Comment: Have you contacted the manufacturer or read the manual to see what the manufacturer's recommendations with regards to installation are?  They would know best, and brand specific questions are generally off topic on this site as per the [faq]

Answer (score 2):

#### High Loop/Air Gap is the Issue

Dishwashers get water in & pump water out. Water coming in is under pressure so there is no issue. Water going out from MOST fixtures is not an issue - a simple modest slope for gravity feed will do. However, a dishwasher is required to have an **air gap** of some sort. This prevents sewer water from flowing back into the dishwasher, which could happen easily if you did not have an air gap and your sink backed up even a little bit.

There are two solutions:

- **Air Gap** - A traditional air gap is a metal/plastic gadget on the corner of your sink. A hose runs up from the dishwasher to the air gap. The water pushes out of the top, literally through the air, and down into another hose. The second hose connects to your disposal or to your drain pipe above the trap.
- **High Hose Loop** - Many areas allow a high hose loop instead. This is one hose that goes from the bottom of the dishwasher up as high as possible under the counter (must be higher than the bottom of the sink) and then down to the disposal or drain pipe above the trap.

If you install a dishwasher next to a sink then this all works great. If you install it with other cabinets or appliances in between then there are two ways to route the discharge hose:

- **Up & Out** Use either a High Hose Loop or Air Gap very close to the dishwasher, and then route the hose, making sure that it slopes down the whole way, to the disposal/drain. This requires space inside the cabinets, which may be really easy or may be a problem. For example, if you have a cooktop/oven in between the dishwasher and the sink then there may be very little, if any, room to route a hose up for a high loop or air gap. In addition, you definitely do NOT want to use an air gap as any excess water spray (which should never happen, but it can) will end up on your counter instead of in your sink. However, this should be just fine as far as the dishwasher pumping capability as the exact same pumping would be needed as with an ordinary installation.
- **Out & Up** Route the discharge hose horizontally until you get to the sink and then up to a High Loop or Air Gap. This is likely to be easier as you can use the toe kick area and/or the very back of the cabinets to route the hose. However, the pump has to do more work to push out and then up than to simply push up **and** there will be more water potentially pooling from the end of the cycle because the hose (up to the high loop or air gap) will hold more water. **I believe this is the manufacturer's concern.**

I don't know if any other brands work better than Bosch in this regard. I don't normally see dishwashers except either right next to the sink or one bay over (typically that is with 2 dishwashers side-by-side).

8 feet sounds like a lot. That is ~ 4 bays away based on typical cabinets. If you can't mount a high hose loop close to the dishwasher then I would be very concerned as to whether it will work properly or not.

Answer (score 1):

I see that many dishwasher manufacturers sell ~6ft. extension hoses (e.g. Bosch model# SGZ1010UC) for their dishwashers, which make the drain hose length with attached extension something like 10 or 12 feet, so I think the eight foot distance to the drain is not a problem at all. The crucial fact is how you have the drain pipe routed, not so much the length of it.

If you use the **"Up & Out"** method **@manassehkatz** mentions, you should be OK. In an arrangement like that, the pump only has to be strong enough to push the water to the high point in the drain tube, and then *gravity moves the water to the drain* without putting any additional work on the pump.

I have my dishwasher installed about 10 feet from my sink drain (using a "homemade" extension tube) and it works like a charm, but again, the high point in the drain tube is pretty much next to the dishwasher and gravity keeps the water moving to the drain.